# Failed to load component dependency "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base"

Tags: spfx

Getting this error after ugrading to SPFX GA and running on a dev tenant....
anyone else getting this?

> [SPWebPartErrorCode.ScriptLoadError]:: Unable to load web part
>   WebPart.PropertyBagDisplayWebPart.041d6977-71c8-4751-81aa-4529a119ace1,Error:
>   ***Failed to load component "fa63037d-d7bd-4d52-894a-b40127773283" (PropertyBagDisplayWebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load
>   component dependency "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base" from component
>   "fa63037d-d7bd-4d52-894a-b40127773283" (PropertyBagDisplayWebPart).
>   script resources due to: {1}. CALLSTACK:: Error at t [as constructor]
>   (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-13.012/sp-loader_en-us_e10f93aa29d8eff41e6d241bc285557f.js:57:21452)
>   at new t
>   (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-13.012/sp-webpart-base_en-us_fbedfc4c29d013d7a0d32e62a349ff62.js:47:21988)
>   at Function.t.create
>   (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-13.012/sp-webpart-base_en-us_fbedfc4c29d013d7a0d32e62a349ff62.js:47:22429)
>   at
>   https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-13.012/sp-webpart-base_en-us_fbedfc4c29d013d7a0d32e62a349ff62.js:48:627

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your farm doesn't have the GA bits rolled to it yet.  The URLs for GA will have 2017-02-17 in it.  It should be on 100% of the farms by Monday evening.