# spfx webpart with angular error

Tags: spfx, angular2

I'm following the few examples I could find about implementing a spfx webpart with angular2. I get this error when deploying to the site workbench (../layouts/workbench.aspx)

> [SPWebPartErrorCode.ScriptLoadError]:: Unable to load web part WebPart.WpAngularTest2WebPart.b233d030-a920-4c7c-b68f-6ee216958ae1,Error: ***Failed to load component "3c175eae-302b-4af5-b943-48227ffd91b7" (WpAngularTest2WebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load component dependency "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base" from component "3c175eae-302b-4af5-b943-48227ffd91b7" (WpAngularTest2WebPart). script resources due to: {1}. CALLSTACK:: Error at t [as constructor] (/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-13.012/sp-loader_en-us_e10f93aa29d8eff41e6d241bc285557f.js:57:21452) at new t (/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-13.012/sp-webpart-base_en-us_fbedfc4c29d013d7a0d32e62a349ff62.js:47:21988) at Function.t.create (/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-13.012/sp-webpart-base_en-us_fbedfc4c29d013d7a0d32e62a349ff62.js:47:22429) at /files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-13.012/sp-webpart-base_en-us_fbedfc4c29d013d7a0d32e62a349ff62.js:48:627

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SPFx GA has not reached your tenant yet.

At your end, the files are available dated 13th Feb `files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-13.012`. The GA file version is `files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-17.019`

Once this is updated, the webpart will start working. Wait till tomorrow according to below link -

[SPFx failed to load components](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/209128/8068)

Comment: Thanks, using the browser developer dashboard i can see the files from the server are dated to 2017_-02-13 so i dont thinks that the problem.

Comment: The files need to be 2017-02-17.019. 17th Feb. This will get updated by tomorrow, the 13th Feb version is older one, hence not working.

Comment: Hi, The version did updated to 2017-02-17.019. 17th Feb on my site but now i get the same error for this date: https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-17.019/sp-loader_en-us_c7a5ee2faf8f15c3c9ab1ecc5e7db21d.js:57:21740) at new ...

Comment: @LiorGal - thats strange , can you edit the question with the new error message ? Also, can you create a simple new hello world webpart and check ?

Comment: hi, i added the new error. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The New error today is:
SPWebPartErrorCode.ScriptLoadError]:: Unable to load web part WebPart.WpAngularTest2WebPart.g_eacdc229_6eb0_472c_ba02_c5b206237fdf,Error: ***Failed to load component "3c175eae-302b-4af5-b943-48227ffd91b7" (WpAngularTest2WebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load path dependency "wpAngularTest2Strings" from component "3c175eae-302b-4af5-b943-48227ffd91b7" (WpAngularTest2WebPart). script resources due to: {1}. CALLSTACK:: Error at t [as constructor] (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-17.019/sp-loader_en-us_c7a5ee2faf8f15c3c9ab1ecc5e7db21d.js:57:21740) at new t (spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-17.019/sp-webpart-base_en-us_f7b0b90820799ba53083111c72956e29.js:47:22746) at Function.t.create (spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-17.019/sp-webpart-base_en-us_f7b0b90820799ba53083111c72956e29.js:47:23187) at https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-02-17.019/sp-webpart-base_en-us_f7b0b90820799ba53083111c72956e29.js:48:6311

It ssems to be working off and on after i clear the browser cache but i cant put my fingure on the cause yet.

It seeme to be working only on chrome browser (not on ie) and i needed to re install and 
clean the browser cache. 
Many thanks to Gautam Sheth for is help.